# SELECT LATEST ENTRY ON GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

This query doesn't return the "latest" entry, rather it returns the "older" rows:

```
 SELECT MAX(ID), ID, NEW_BALANCE, DATE, NAME, ACC_NO 
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT ID, NEW_BALANCE, DATE, NAME, ACC_NO 
  FROM account_logs 
  WHERE customer_id = 1061 
  ORDER BY DATE DESC, ID DESC 
) AS sub 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY DATE ASC ;
```

The following inner query:

```
SELECT ID, NEW_BALANCE, DATE, NAME, ACC_NO 
FROM account_logs 
WHERE customer_id = 1061 
ORDER BY DATE DESC, ID DESC
```

...perfectly arranges the rows by the latest entries:

[image: Picture of DB]

I would like to GROUP BY the latest entries, rather I get this:

[image: Group By doesn't filter by latest entry]

The rows I need:

[image: My expectations]

Comment: Above (first) statement is not correct fo `sql-server`, so your tags are wrong. Also add some data for input and needed output, and a proper description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you please provide DDL for your table `account_logs ` and maybe some DML. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might like to take a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! 8-)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? MySQL 8 supports window functions, which simplifies this kind of query a lot. For earlier versions, you can mimic those with variables. The latter aint pretty, but it may be worth looking into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM account_logs 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT MAX(ID)
  FROM account_logs 
  WHERE customer_id = 1061 
  GROUP BY DATE )
ORDER BY DATE ASC ;
```

The sub-query should return all the ID's that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the optimizer to use `index` you can use self join and get the result.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, t1.NEW_BALANCE, t1.DATE, t1.NAME, t1.ACC_NO
FROM
    account_logs t1
        LEFT JOIN
    account_logs t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
        AND t1.DATE = t2.DATE
        AND t1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.customer_id = 1061 AND t2.ID IS NULL
```